# Metalsmith: How to use run()?

Tags: metalsmith

The docs show a method `run(files, fn)`:

> Run all of the middleware functions on a dictionary of `files` and callback with `fn(err, files)`, where `files` is the altered dictionary.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/metalsmith#runfiles-fn

**How / When should it be used?** I cannot find any more detailed information or examples.

Thanks for any hints :)